# Configuring SSL in IIS / ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-6, httpmodule

I'll try to be as brief as I can. I have the certificate already setup on my server. I just have a question about the.. proper way of configuring the ssl in my website.

I need to secure at the root `login.aspx` and the `admin` and `cart` directories. So in IIS, you can right-click a file or directory in the site and go to `Properties` -> `File/Directory Security` tab -> `Secure Communications` section and click `Edit` -> check `Require secure channel (SSL)`. This causes the file or directory contents to be requested over `https` connection, and asp.net will not convert the request automatically.

So, instead of changing all of my links and redirects to use absolute URLs to specify `http` or `https`, I implemented an [http module](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7206/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically-Ver) to automatically switch between between `http` and `https` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222195/550309). However, I still get the error:

> The page must be viewed over a secure channel

because it was not *initially* sent over `https`, but converted in the module. If I remove the setting in IIS, it works fine; the page module automatically switches the connection to `https`. My question is, is it okay to not have the SSL requirement setting in IIS and just have my http module handle the http/https switching? I feel like I will be losing a layer of security here by doing so. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: I think that you get this message because you do not left the http page runs at all, (so this modules can not find them and switch from http to https). I use the same module some years now and have not issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is acceptable to not enable the `Require secure channel` option. I have only enabled that option when an entire domain needs to be secured, like secure.domain.com. For sites that have parts that need to be HTTPS and parts that I don't, I use the switcher method that you described. When the user requests the login page they are redirected to the same page over HTTPS. All cookies are set to only be delivered over SSL:

```
<system.web>
        <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />
</system.web>
```

If the cookie is absent then the user is not logged in and pages are delivered over HTTP.