# ASP.NET Securing Cookie on HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, security, cookies

I have a site that has both HTTP and HTTPS pages.

I have tried the following to make cookies secure:

- Web.config `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` with form authentication.
- Forcing cookie to secure at `Application_End`

In both case pages don't work with HTTP. I think above solution only works if all the pages use HTTPS.

How to resolved this puzzle?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't make all pages use HTTPS?

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of a cookie set as 'secure' is that it is *only* transmitted over https; the http pages will not receive a copy of it. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie):

> A secure cookie has the secure attribute enabled and is only used via HTTPS, ensuring that the cookie is always encrypted when transmitting from client to server. This makes the cookie less likely to be exposed to cookie theft via eavesdropping.

If you want to use a secure cookie, you need to ensure that all the pages use https.

Comment: I have constrain - I can not move all website into https. Is there any way to fix this issue or alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately not; your http-served pages will not get the cookie whilst it is set as 'secure'. The only way is for the secure setting to be removed.

Comment: You could, at a stretch, use a normal insecure cookie, encrypt the data inside it, and also encrypt some origin-related information in it (for example, which IP address requests should come from). But that's still vulnerable to interception - e.g. if an attacker manages to get on the same network - and the origin IP address could change causing further problems. Not to mention that it may well not pass any security audits.

Answer (score 3):

The Question: *How to resolved this puzzle* , requires an   analysis of the requirements  and see if it would be better to use https for whole website or  a combination of http & https.

***Since you are also asking for an alternative in one of your above comments, I hope the below info may help you decide on alternatives***.

**Background:**

Basically you use http for all pages that have nothing  to do with sensitive data, and https on the pages that have sensitive data.
Many times we don't prefer to use https for whole website as the data that travels is more and it  takes time to  encrypt and decrypt them , thereby adding up to the actual time it takes to load/display a page.

However, there are arguments against above common notion and you can also find encouragement to use https for your whole website. Check this: [How to implement HTTPS only on part of website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926145/how-to-implement-https-only-on-part-of-website)

And, YES, secure cookies can only be used on `https` pages.

**Some suggestions**

- You should protect your sensitive data and this applies to Cookies too. If bad has to happen, check here how bad it can happen: [Can some hacker steal the cookie from a user and login with that name on a web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498599/can-some-hacker-steal-the-cookie-from-a-user-and-login-with-that-name-on-a-web-s)
- You may divide your User data to secure and non secure. For example, on `Flipkart.com`,   We see that normally you can browse through the various items, do search , view details of every single item  etc.., and all such pages are `http` only. The interesting part comes when you finally proceed with buying and all those pages are `https`. This link can help you get started on this concept: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5523/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically  OR: [Setting up SSL page only on login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561483/setting-up-ssl-page-only-on-login-page/6561544)

Comment: How is any of this relevant to the question? Seriously?

Comment: He can't use secure cookies on http page. In the end he asked that how to resolve this puzzle?. So It will be good to help him think and see what exactly is the requirement and that he may resolve this puzzle so that either he will use https as a whole or a combination rather than trying waste to access secure cookies on http page.

Comment: Also in one of above comments user mentioned that it's not possible for him to use https on whole website. And HE DID ASKED FOR ALTERNATIVES. so i just tried to give .

Comment: @Adrian: My sincere apologies Friend if I offended in any way. I just wanted to help the user get clarity on his alternative options available as he demanded the same.